# Select2 multiple cannot set default

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am getting the data from ajax and filling the select with it. Now How can make default selections in this.

Here are my ajax

```
var productLists =[];
$.when(http_get('admin/offer/data/sync')).then(function(response){

    //returns a products array

    $.each(response.products, function(i, item){
            var product = {};
            product['id'] = item.id;
            product['text'] = item.product_name;
            productLists[i] = product;
    });
});
$('#sel_product').select2({
    data: productLists
});
```

To get seleted values I can do another ajax list

Or I can print `<otpion value="" selected="selected">` in the html from php.

So here how do i make default selection with select2?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the call to `.select2()` into the callback, so it will be initialized after the data is retrieved.

```
var productLists = [];
$.when(http_get('admin/offer/data/sync')).then(function(response){
    //returns a products array
    $.each(response.products, function(i, item){
            var product = {};
            product['id'] = item.id;
            product['text'] = item.product_name;
            productLists[i] = product;
    });

    $('#sel_product').select2({
        data: productLists
    });
});
```

Comment: There is no problem with the data initialization. I need to know how to set the default `selected='selected'` values.